# Compilation error when trying to access the structure member with operator(->)

Tags: c, operator-keyword

I have a small inconvenience with this operator is that when compiling the code i will show below gives me the following error: error #2112: Left operand of '->' has incompatible type 'person' do not understand because it happens.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct human{

    int *works;

}person;

int main(){

    int i,j,cont=1;
    int quantity_person=8;
    int quantity_works=4;
    person *first;
    first=(person *)malloc(sizeof(person)*quantity_person);

    first->works=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*quantity_works);


    for (i = 0; i < quantity_person; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < quantity_works; j++){

            first[i]->works[j]=cont;
            cont++;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < quantity_person; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < quantity_works; j++){

            printf("%d ",first[i]->works[j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

thanks a lot

Comment: Well, you don't have a type _person_ defined, do you? What you do have, is a struct _human_.

Comment: type of `first[i]` is not pointer. `first[i]->works[j]` --> `first[i].works[j]`. also `first->works...` need each first[index].

Comment: then what is the way appropriate access to "works"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `first[i]` is not a pointer, to access its fields you must use `.` instead of `->`.
2. You need to allocate memory for each instance of your `first` array

Here's your fixed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct human{

    int *works;

}person;

int main(){

    int i,j,cont=1;
    int quantity_person=8;
    int quantity_works=4;
    person *first;
    first=(person *)malloc(sizeof(person)*quantity_person);

    for (i = 0; i < quantity_person; i++){
        first[i].works=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*quantity_works);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < quantity_person; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < quantity_works; j++){

            first[i].works[j]=cont;
            cont++;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < quantity_person; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < quantity_works; j++){

            printf("%d ",first[i].works[j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your line

```
first[i]->works[j]
```

should probably be

```
first[i].works[j]
```

as first[i] is not a pointer

Comment: that way it gives me segmentation fault

Comment: you only malloced works for the first item of your first[i] array. You need to allocate the space for each one.

Comment: then it would be: first[i]->works = malloc(sizeof(int) * quantity_works);